# 2001 Chevy Blazer- Odorless liquid coming out from the rear side next to the gas tank

Tags: chevrolet, blazer, fluid-leak

After driving my ‘01 Chevy Blazer on the highway I started noticing a clear fluid coming from a rubber piece next to the gas compartment. I tried to identify what was it, it is odorless, cool and clear. I looked up and saw that it could be the brake fluid. I checked the brake fluid levels and it was on Max. Also the truck makes some can of roaring noises when accelerating but sometimes it doesn’t do it. Please help and thank you guys.

[image] 
 Thats the little piece the liquid is coming from[image]

That’s the piece the liquid is coming from, the first one is where it’s coming out the most, the second one it’s from the right side.

Comment: Looks like a water drain - anyone left a bottle of water not capped, or spilt a drink or is there a leak on a rear window / has one been left open? You would know if it was brake fluid - that smells....

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Is there a factory moonroof installed in the Blazer? This could be the drain for it if it is.

Comment: What does the liquid feel like?

Answer (score 1):

Its water from the environment, road, a spill or condensation.

Please refer to the following list of colorless, tasteless and odorless vehicle fluids: